# Passing Data from Slide menu to UITableViewController through UINavigationViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, ecslidingviewcontroller

How can I pass data from UINavigationController to The root UITableViewController?
I have implemented the ECSlidingViewController (https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController). User selects one of the cells in the menu that correspond to different urls I want to display information from on my tableView that sitts on top of the UINavigationController. (u know the default combination that u get my dragging UINavigationController to ur storyboard). I am able to get the data from the sliding menu to my navigationController now I am trying to pass that same info on my tableview?

In my menu I have:

```
 UINavigationController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationTop"];
    newTopViewController = [(NavigationTopViewController*)newTopViewController initWithCinema:self.myCinema];
```

In UINaviationController:

```
    - (id)initWithCinema:(Cinema *)cinema {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _myCinema = [[Cinema alloc] init];
        _myCinema = cinema;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // this log works I get the info to here.
    NSLog(@"url(navigation):%@", self.myCinema.cinemaURL);

    //MoviesTableViewController *moviesTableViewController = [[MoviesTableViewController alloc] initWithCinema:self.myCinema];

    //UITableViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoviesTable"];

    //NavigationTopViewController *newTopViewController = [[NavigationTopViewController alloc] initWithCinema:self.myCinema];
    //newTopViewController = [(MoviesTableViewController *)newTopViewController initWithCinema:self.myCinema];
    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:nil sender:self.myCinema];
    [self prepareForSegue:nil sender:self.myCinema.cinemaURL];

}
```

In my UITableView:

```
  - (void)setCinema:(Cinema *)cinema {
    // works here too
    NSLog(@"Table(setCinema):%@", cinema.cinemaURL);
    self.myCinema = [[Cinema alloc] init];
    if(!cinema) {
        cinema.cityIndex = kAstanaIndex;
        cinema.name = kKeruen;
        cinema.nameForText = kKeruenText;
        cinema.cinemaURL = kKeruenURL;
        cinema.cinemaURLTomorrow = kKeruenURLtomorrow;
    }
    self.myCinema = cinema;
    // works here too!!!
    NSLog(@"Table(myCinema):%@", self.myCinema.cinemaURL);
}
```

However its gone in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set delegate to self
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    // set loading theater's url


// does not work here: I GET NULL !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    NSLog(@"url(moviesTable):%@", self.myCinema.cinemaURL);
    _model = [[MovieModel alloc] initWithURL:self.myCinema.cinemaURL];
}
```

None of the methods I have tried (commented in Navigation worked...) at least for me. Please give me any suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For clarification, you have a `topViewController` set to a `UINavigationController` which has a `UITableViewController` as the root view controller? You want pass data from one of your under view controllers to the table view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UINavigationController` does not hold any data, but rather a stack of view controllers. I'd recommend you check out frameworks such as the free Sensible TableView. The framework will automatically handle detail view generation and passing data between them. Saves me tons of development time in my projects.